# How to draw multiple cuboids on the same plot

Tags: graphics, graphics3d

I have defined a table

```
Table[Table[
  Graphics3D[
   Cuboid[radijDensity[[j, i]] {-Sin[kotiDensity[[j, i]]], 
      1 - Cos[kotiDensity[[j, i]]], 0}, {radijDensity[[j, i]]*
      Sin[kotiDensity[[j, i]]], 
     radijDensity[[j, i]] (1 - Cos[kotiDensity[[j, i]]]) + 
      visina[[j, i + 1]], 0}]], {i, 1, n + m - 10}], {j, 1, 
  Length[force[[All, 1]]], 1}]
```

of cuboids.

But what I want is to have all of them on the same plot but at different z axis values. And I don't know how to do it. Something like `ListPlot3D` just that I want it to show those cuboids.

Comment: "different z axis values" - then you should be changing the $z$-coordinates on the corners of the `Cuboid[]`, no?

Comment: I think not. Because doing so, will add third dimension to the cuboids. And I don't want that. I want them to remain 2D - so it is actually a rectangle but I used `Cuboid[]` in mathematica only because I want a 3D plot.
So the idea is if you imagine an arbitrary shaped sasuage (3D object) I want to show only some slices at specified z values, if z axis is along the sausage. Is that understandable?

Comment: Oh yeah... And by "all" cuboids I mean for all indexes `i` at given index value `j`, if I use the same notation as in the OP. The idea is to than use `Manipulate[]` for index `j`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its difficult to work with your question since you don't define your functions and variables but hopefully this example will be enough.

Let's first make a table of cuboids with different z values (but using the same z-value within each cuboid so they are still rectangles). This examples uses the same x and y values for every `Cuboid` for simplicity, but you can obviously change that.

```
list = Table[Cuboid[{0, 0, z}, {1, 1, z}], {z, 1, 5}]
```

Now apply `Graphics3D` to the list of cuboids

```
Graphics3D @ list
```

[image: Picture of Result]

By putting different z values for each cuboid, they appear at different levels.

Comment: Doesn't `Graphics3D @ list` work?

Comment: Yes, it actually does. I'm still somewhat new to Mathematica and didn't know Graphics3D could take multiple regions until you said that.  I'll modify the post since that is cleaner. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> Something like ListPlot3D just that I want it to show those cuboids.

If you need to place the same shape at multiple points either in 2D or 3D, the best solution is [`Translate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Translate.html).  It can take more than one translation vector as the second argument.

Example:

```
pts = RandomReal[10, {20, 3}];

Graphics3D[
 Translate[
  Cuboid[],
  pts
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]